# Display Image & Text Side By Side In React Native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, view

I need some help regarding react-native images side by side. I am unable to get it done in the right way.
I want these images to display side by side, in two columns and 2 rows.
Here is my code

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text>Sample</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                  onPress={() =>
                    Linking.openURL(
                      "#"
                    )
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    source={transport}
                    style={{ width: 150, height: 120, padding: 50 }}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>Sample</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                  onPress={() =>
                    Linking.openURL(
                      "#"
                    )
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    source={entertainment}
                    style={{ width: 150, height: 120, padding: 50 }}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>Sample</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                  onPress={() =>
                    Linking.openURL(
                      "#"
                    )
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    source={doorkay}
                    style={{ width: 150, height: 120, padding: 50 }}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>Sample</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                  onPress={() =>
                    Linking.openURL(
                      "#"
                    )
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    source={blood}
                    style={{ width: 150, height: 120, padding: 50 }}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bIiP.png)
I am also attaching the result which i got. Please help. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Have u tried flex layouts.

Comment: not much idea how to implement in this code. Can you guide @asutosh! thanks

Comment: i tried this and didn't worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209843/render-two-items-images-side-by-side-in-a-list-view-in-react-native

Comment: @sayed Put a JSFiddle here to understand what problem you are facing while trying with Flex layout.

Comment: Can you show me any example of flex layout which works with my approach. I have shared what i applied @Asutosh and a link too but both approaches failed. the problem i am facing is the one image is taking the whole width and the next one is below that image. Check https://imgur.com/a/57FCey6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can take a look at snacks that I created here: https://snack.expo.io/@shawwals/image-side-by-side

Hopefully it can help you.